# React Native - stickyHeaderIndices not working for SectionList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-sectionlist, react-native-stylesheet

I am trying to make some header to stick to the top of the SectionList but it seems like the `stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}` doesn't work as expected. This is the section list:

```
     <SectionList
          ref={(ref) => (productsSectionListRef = ref)}
          stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
          ListHeaderComponent={_renderHeader()}
          contentContainerStyle={[style.products_container]}
          sections={productListSections}
          renderItem={({item, section}: {item: string; section: any}) => {
            return _renderProduct(item);
          }}
          stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
          renderSectionHeader={({section}) => {
            return _renderProductHeader(section.title);
          }}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          viewabilityConfig={{
            itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50,
          }}
          onViewableItemsChanged={_onViewableItemsChanged}
          bounces={false}
          scrollEventThrottle={4}
          initialNumToRender={productListSections.length}
          scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled}
          removeClippedSubviews={true}/>
```

I tryed to put the header outside the section list but the header it's bigger and I cannot scroll inside of that header component.

Answer (score 0):

```
stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
```

will make first item in flatlist sticky to the top
if you change to

```
stickyHeaderIndices={[5]}
```

the 4th item will stick to top after the item reached to the top when scrolled

item in

```
ListHeaderComponent={_renderHeader()}
```

will be on top of the flatlist but not act as item inside flatlist its independent